# KendoUI Grid - MVVM Bindings - object Object] has no method 'isNew'

Tags: mvvm, grid, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI grid which I'm using with MVVM bindings. I also have a UI where a user can enter data and select an Add button. Upon pressing the add button the new data is added to the model. The grid is set to Autosync.

The problem I have is that once a new item is added I get an error "[object Object] has no method isNew"

My grid is as follows:

```
      $("#objJoinGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                create: function (operation) {
                    operation.success();
                },
                update: function (operation) {
                    operation.success();
                },
                destroy: function (operation) {
                    operation.success();
                },
                read: function (operation) {
                    operation.success(datasetMetaModel.joinList.ObjectList);                        
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "JOIN_OBJECT_ID",
                    fields: {
                        JOIN_OBJECT_ID: { type: "number" },
                        JOIN_OBJECT_NAME: { type: "string" }                            
                    }
                }
            },
            autoSync: true
        },
        height: 220,
        columns: [
            { field: "JOIN_OBJECT_ID", width: "130px" },
            { field: "JOIN_OBJECT_NAME", width: "130px" }        
        ]            
     });
```

I then bind my model to the grid:

```
   datasetMetaModel = kendo.observable({
        joinList: datasetModel.JoinStructure,
    });

    kendo.bind($("#areaDiv"), datasetMetaModel);
```

And in the click event of the Add button:

```
$("#addDataset").bind("click", function () {
    var dropdownlistPO = $("#objectListing").data("kendoDropDownList");

    datasetMetaModel.joinList.ObjectList.push({
        JOIN_OBJECT_ID: dropdownlistPO.value(),
        JOIN_OBJECT_NAME: dropdownlistPO.text()
    });
});
```

In this instance datasetModel.JoinStructure is an empty array which comes from the server. The odd thing is that if I actually add one entry to the server then everything works, I can add new items without issue.  Any ideas? I'm guessing it's something to do with how I'm adding the new item.

Comment: If I disable AutoSync I can then add successfully to the grid.  However the error reappears when I call grid.sync().  This is really odd behaviour, I cannot see what the issue could be with my code. A Kendo bug maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your create to actually return the newly created record. e.g.

```
create: function(e) {
        var item = e.data;
        item.Id = data.length + 1;
        e.success(item);
    }
```

Here is live example that should be pretty similar to yours.

http://jsbin.com/iDeloNo/1/edit

Comment: The problem is that the Create function is never triggered. I'm adding the new record to the Model and not directly to the grid. The new record is added when an item is selected from a dropdown list.  In my Model the ID field is JOIN_OBJECT_ID when I add a new record to my model I add it with a unique JOIN_OBJECT_ID value.  I'm using MVVM bindings.